# How to explode range (from two column) to rows

Tags: python, pandas

Hello all I have this:

`df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['L1', 'L2'], 'from':['1', '5'], 'to':['3', '7']})`

```
name    from    to
L1       1       3
L2       5       7
```

In fact I have a lot of row (3000000) and very big range like 1 to 9000.

What is the best way to have this kind of result (exploding the range in rows)

like:

```
name    n°
L1       1
L1       2
L1       3
L2       5
L2       6
L2       7
```

Thank's a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprehension with `range` and `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df[['from','to']] = df[['from','to']].astype(int)

zipped = zip(df['name'], df['from'], df['to'])
df = pd.DataFrame([(i, y) for i,j,k in zipped for y in range(j, k+1)], columns=['name','id'])
print (df)
  name  id
0   L1   1
1   L1   2
2   L1   3
3   L2   5
4   L2   6
5   L2   7
```

Another solution:

```
df[['from','to']] = df[['from','to']].astype(int)

s = df['to'] - df['from'] + 1
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(s), ['name','from']].rename(columns={'from':'no'})
df['no'] += df.groupby(level=0).cumcount()
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
  name  no
0   L1   1
1   L1   2
2   L1   3
3   L2   5
4   L2   6
5   L2   7
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(pd.concat([df, df[['from', 'to']]
           .applymap(int)
           .apply(lambda x: np.arange(x[0], x[1]), axis=1)], 
          axis=1)
.explode(0))
```

Output:

```
    name    from    to  0
0   L1         1    3   1
0   L1         1    3   2
1   L2         5    7   5
1   L2         5    7   6
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**: sorry I got the questions wrong 1st time, I corrected by answer

As pandas data are stored as numpy array internally and numpy manipulations are fast you can use numpy manipulation to do it

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['L1', 'L2'], 'from':[1, 5], 'to':[3, 7]})

t_dict = {}
## find number of times each rows should be repeated
repeats = (df["to"]- df["from"]+1 ).values

## repeat names
t_dict["name"] = df["name"].values.repeat(repeats)

## repeat notes and add 0,1,2,3 .. seq to each repeated section
t_dict["n°"] = df["from"].values.repeat(repeats) + np.array([i for count in repeats for i in range(count)])

pd.DataFrame(t_dict)
```

**output**

```
name    n°
0   L1  1
1   L1  2
2   L1  3
3   L2  5
4   L2  6
5   L2  7
```